How to create dynamic data model in Entity Framework?
I'm currently developing a JobList API that interfaces between a SQL stored procedure and Entity Framework. I've created only one data model, but I'm facing an issue: when I try to retrieve a single job, it results in an error because the data model for the whole job list doesn't match the data model for a single job. However, I can't create a separate data model for every situation.
Is it possible to dynamically create a data model to match the single job retrieval while maintaining the whole list model?
I expected when I call single job list, Entity Framework dynamically creates a data model.

Not entirely clear what you mean; I would have expected that you have a JobModel class for a single job, and you either return that model from the method to fetch a single job, or a List<JobModel> from your method to fetch a list of jobs .... so basically, you would have just a single model class - once you return one instance of that, another time you return a list (or collection) of such class instances - no?

I apologise for my earlier unclear explanation.
I have a stored procedure that returns two types of data: complete data and single job data using a job ID. The problem is that the single job data doesn't match the existing data model. For example, the complete data shows different jobs and -1 for non-existent jobs. However, the single job call doesn’t return non-existent data, which causes a mismatch. I can't create a separate data model for each case, so I want to dynamically create the data model when the stored procedure returns a single value.

First of all, this seems like a horribly bad design decision - a stored procedure (like a method in code in general) should really only ever return ONE type / shape of data. No DB technology can handle this situation very well - and EF really only works well when you know what data you're working with. EF cannot magically just look a the result set and dynamically build C# classes to handle that .....
